# Beeline usage instead of hive in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, hive, beeline

In my shell script I am using this query to get the last_value of the column id.

```
last_val=`beeline -e "select nvl(max(id),0) from testing.1_test"`
```

The result is

```
+----------+--+
|   _c0    |
+----------+--+
| 3380901  |
+----------+--+
```

Now I want to pass this value as variable ${last_val}

when I do echo `${last_val}` I want to have `3380901` but I am receiving

```
+----------+--+
|   _c0    |
+----------+--+
| 3380901  |
+----------+--+
```

How can I echo `3380901`.

When I used hive option like below I got what I want

```
last_val=`hive -e "select nvl(max(id),0) from testing.1_test"`
```

echo `${last_val}` gave me `3380901`

Please let me know how can I do this?

Comment: What is the output of `beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=csv2 -e "select nvl(max(id),0) from testing.1_test"`?

Comment: @MirosławZalewski `    +----------+--+
                                      | 3380901  |
                                     +----------+--+`                                                        is the output but I want `3380901`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
last_val=`beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -e "select nvl(max(id),0) from testing.1_test"`
```